# Montar Query com JOINS

Tags: java, sql, db2

Tenho um query executada no DB2:

```
SELECT f.* 
       FROM Fat f 
            INNER EFat ef 
                  ON f.id = ef.id AND f.seq = ef.seq
```

Como faço a reversa dela no Java? Tentei dessa forma, mas dá erro, todas as minhas classes estão com os seus devidos relacionamentos:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT f FROM ")
.append(getClasseGenerica().getSimpleName() + " f ")
.append(" INNER JOIN f.eFaturas ef ")
```

Minha dúvida é para fazer, isso:

```
ON f.id = ef.id AND f.seq = ef.seq
```

Com isso no JAVA:

```
.append(" AND f.id = ef.id AND f.seq = ef.seq ")
 Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sb.toString());
```

Quando coloco `AND` ou `WHERE` sempre dá erro na execução da query.

Comment: Na pergunta tem um `AND` no lugar do `ON`

Comment: Não entendi o que informou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JPQL só é possível fazer o inner join da forma que você está tentando quando as classe são relacionadas (Ex. Detro de Fat tem um Atributo do tipo Efat).

Como alternativa você pode fazer a querie da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT f 
FROM Fat f,  EFat ef 
WHERE f.id = ef.id 
    AND f.seq = ef.seq
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Ou você pode fazer conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Fat f 
    in(f.eFaturas) ef 
WHERE  f.seq = ef.seq
```

Comment: Marciano,no meu caso todas as classes estão relacionadas. Como poderia fazer da maneira que estou tentando?

Comment: Coloquei mais um exemplo de como fazer dessa forma, verifique por favor.

Comment: Tentei usando essa forma, mas continua dando erro na criação da query.

Comment: Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1715851 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encontrado "ef" no caractere 306, mas esperado: ["*", "+", "-", "/", "AND", "GROUP", "HAVING", "OR", "ORDER", <EOF>].

Comment: Você consegue exibir a querie que o seu sistema esta criando ? Se possível exiba também suas entidade que facilitará encontrar o problema.

Comment: Conseguir resolver o problema, como já está tudo relacionado essa parte .append(" AND f.id = ef.id AND f.seq = ef.seq ") que estava querendo fazer não precisa, porque pelo o mapeamento já faz isso, então basta somente passar o os dados finais que desejava igual informou e funcionou. Valeu